# Pycharm : [Errno 10054]

Tags: robotframework

I try to Run a simple robot framework script in PyCharm.Here is my code:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  This is some basic info about the whole suite
Library  Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***

*** Test Cases ***
User must sign in to check out
    [Documentation]  This is some basic info about the test
    [Tags]  Smoke
    Open Browser  http://www.google.com.ua chrome
    Close Browser
```

I customized robot framework with PyCharm as it was in videos but when I run this script in terminal of PyCharm, the desired site isn't opened and I get the next information:

```
C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\amazon>
C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\amazon>pybot -d results tests/Amazon.robot


Amazon :: This is some basic info about the whole suite

[ WARN ] Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: No browser is open
User must sign in to check out :: This is some basic info about th... | FAIL |
error: [Errno 10054]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Amazon :: This is some basic info about the whole suite               | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\amazon\results\output.xml
Log:     C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\amazon\results\log.html
Report:  C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\amazon\results\report.html
```

Tell me, please, why this script doesn't open the browser and actions that it should execute and why do I get this error. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have chrome installed and what system are you on?

Comment: What is in the generated log.html? There is more information in there.

Answer (score 1):

If the code you posted is literally your code, you're missing at least one space before `chrome` on the `open browser` line. There must be two or more spaces between the URL and the browser.

This may not be the only problem, but it's definitely a problem.